# Same as Object.keys(), but excluding properties that are of type Function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

[This method](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/master/src/validation/ValidationTypes.ts#L95) uses `Object.keys()` to check if a type is valid:

```
/**
 * Checks if validation type is valid.
 */
static isValid(type: string) {
    return  type !== "isValid" &&
        type !== "getMessage" &&
        Object.keys(this).map(key => (this as any)[key]).indexOf(type) !== -1;
}
```

Curious whether there is something in Javascript / Typescript that automatically excludes the properties that are functions, such that we can eliminate the `type !== "isValid" &&...` parts of the function.

If you know of other simple ways to do this that would be great to see as well.

Comment: Maybe use `.filter()` to exclude the functions? There's nothing particularly special about function values.

Comment: `key && {}.toString.call(key) === '[object Function]'` ?